# Appending to new nodes not yet inserted in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to make my code concise and reduce unnecessary dom rendering, I'm trying to construct and populate a table before appending it to the document.  The problem I'm having is that only the divs are getting appended to the table, so I end up with a table full of divs instead of tr's with td's that contain divs.

I'm pretty sure this is because when I use the `.appendTo` function it's not appending the `td` to the `tr`, and the `tr` to the `table` but instead is removing the div and appending it to each in turn, lastly ending up in the table.

How can I construct a node chain before appending to the document?

Code:

```
    var playerSelect = $( "#playerSelect" );
    var playerElements = [];
    var rowCounter = 0;
    var playerTable = $("<table/>").attr("id", "playerTable");
    for (player in playerBase){
        var playerDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("player").text(player + playerBase[player].rating);
        playerDiv.appendTo("<td/>").appendTo("<tr/>").appendTo(playerTable);                   
    };
    playerSelect.append( playerTable );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.appendTo()` does not accept a string value. `$()` does however, so you could change your code like this:

```
$("<tr />").append($("<td />").append(playerDiv)).appendTo(playerTable);
```

That said, this is not the cleanest way to do it, you might want to have a look at templating engines if you have a lot of these structures in your code.

Comment: I had tried that earlier, and just tried again now but I get the same results.

Comment: Just realised that what is happening in your code snippet is that the playerDiv does get appended to a <td>, but `.appendTo()` returns the playerDiv, instead of the created <td>. See my updated code.

Comment: That was it.  I naively expected `.appendTo` to return the element getting appended to, not the one appended.

Comment: For the record, this isn't actually correct.  On further inspection the divs are appended to the tr's, not the td's.  So it's the same problem really, just from the other end.  Does JQuery have functionality for chaining nodes (recursively? not sure what the word is here) or do I just have to manually declare each tr and td in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (player in playerBase){
var tr = $('<tr/>');
var td = $('<td/>');
     td.appendTo(tr);
        var playerDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("player").text(player + playerBase[player].rating);
        playerDiv.appendTo(td);
       tr.appendTo(playerTable);  
};
```

Comment: Nope, same result.

Comment: oppps the code had error. I just edited it. have a look